# Short story with “Roth Stone” and “Schenken Club” (contract bridge) references

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, crime

I’m looking for a short story published in 1965 or 1966 possibly in “Fantasy and Science Fiction”. It involved a crime mystery and had the terms “Roth Stone” and “Schenken Club”, both obvious contract bridge references.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Randall Garrett's [A Case of Identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Darcy_(character)) contains bridge allusions, though not the ones you specified. From the wiki article

> The story "A Case Of Identity" also contains two subtle references
> to contract bridge, including a magic spell for establishing identity
> called the **Jacoby transfer which requires blood from "at least two
> hearts**." This is an allusion to a bridge convention known as
> transfer bidding, which attempts to make the stronger, concealed hand
> the declarer, and always results in a contract of at least Two Hearts.
> Also in the story, the murder victim is described as having been
> struck with a long club, because "according to
> the **Kaplan–Sheinwold test, a short club cannot have been used." In
> the Kaplan–Sheinwold bidding system, making an opening bid of "one
> club" when holding two or fewer club cards-a "short club"-is not
> permitted.**

Per [isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53599) this story appeared in Analog in 1964, and it is a murder mystery (in a fantasy setting - unusual for Analog, of course).

Comment: That sounds like it! Thanks very much! I've ordered a Kindle book which has it, so I'll soon know for sure.

Comment: Great! If it is the right book, please drop by to give me a checkmark

Comment: Done! (I think…)

Comment: Definitely done. Thanks.